# Why code behind C# button_clicked function doesn't call Javascript function?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to test the C# code side when user click the button, the method in C# function should be able to call the JavaScript function to show alert C# public variable results. Somehow it doesn't call anything at all. At the bottom of `ButtonRequest_Click` function, I wrote `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CreateIsm();", "CreateIsm();", true);` to call `CreateIsm();` function in JavaScript. Maybe this doesn't work?

Here is C# codes,

```
public Collection<PSObject> output = new Collection<PSObject>();
    public string deviceName = "";
    public string ipAddresses = "";
    public string YourScript = "";

protected void ButtonRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        deviceName = string.Empty;
        ipAddresses = string.Empty;
        HiddenName.Visible = false;

        string str = "";
        string ipAddress = "";
        string name = "";

        var tbids = (List<string>)Session["tbids"];

        //create a powershell
        Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runSpace.Open();

        RunspaceInvoke invoke = new RunspaceInvoke();

        Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

        Command invokeScript = new Command("Invoke-Command");

        //Add powershell script file and arguments into scriptblock
        ScriptBlock sb = invoke.Invoke(@"{D:\Scripts\Get-FreeAddress.ps1 '" + DropDownListContainer.SelectedValue + "' " + DropDownListIP.SelectedValue + "}")[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;

        invokeScript.Parameters.Add("scriptBlock", sb);

        invokeScript.Parameters.Add("computername", TextBoxServer.Text);

        pipeline.Commands.Add(invokeScript);

        Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();
        runSpace.Close();
        Runspace runSpace2 = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runSpace2.Open();


        foreach(PSObject psObject in output)
        {
            ipAddress = "" + psObject;
            ipAddresses += "" + psObject;

            foreach(var id in tbids)
                try
                {
                    name = Request[id];
                    deviceName += Request[id] + "\r\n";

                    Pipeline pipeline2 = runSpace2.CreatePipeline();
                    Command invokeScript2 = new Command("Invoke-Command");

                    //Add powershell script file and arguments into scriptblock
                    ScriptBlock sb2 = invoke.Invoke(@"{D:\Scripts\Set-IPAddress.ps1 " + ipAddress + " " + name + "}")[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;

                    invokeScript2.Parameters.Add("scriptBlock", sb2);

                    invokeScript2.Parameters.Add("computername", TextBoxServer.Text);

                    pipeline2.Commands.Add(invokeScript2);


                    tbids.RemoveAt(0);

                    Collection<PSObject> output2 = pipeline2.Invoke();

                    foreach(PSObject psObject2 in output2)
                    {
                        str = str + psObject2;
                    }

                    break;
                }
                catch
                {

                }

        }


        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CreateIsm();", "CreateIsm();", true);

    }
```

Javascript on aspx side in html,

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" CodeBehind="~/Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>

     CreateIsm = function (funct) {

                 alert('<%=ipAddresses%>');
                alert('<%=deviceName%>');
      }; 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     //the are html codes here but I cut it off except ButtonRequest
     <asp:Button ID="ButtonRequest" runat="server" Text="Request" Visible="False" 
            onclick="ButtonRequest_Click" />
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the client side html page look like?

Comment: I edited it above by adding detail of what html look like

Comment: When somebody clicks the button, its too late to register a startup script--the page has already loaded.  `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` runs just fine, but the hook it creates never gets called by the browser

Comment: ok then what way it will work to call javascript function? I already debugged and there are no error exception.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hc29e2a(v=vs.100).ASPX

You can use OnClientClick like this:

```
<asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Ok to post?')" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Click!" />
```